# Route mapper ignoring my custom route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I wanted to add SEF urls to my application, so instead of having links like:
`/home/product/{reference}` (where {reference} is the identifying product reference)

I could have:
`/p-big-silver-microwave/{reference}` (where 'big silver microwave' is the product title)

So i added the route map

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", "p-{any}/{reference}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Product", reference = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

However! Now if the product title (which is used to generate the SEF part of the URL) has a word that ends in 'p' e.g. lamp, the URL generated for it would be:
`/p-lamp-shade/abc123` the route mapper sees both the 1st `p-` and the second `p-` and for some reason ignores the route I have specified.

I thought that specifying a URL of `p-{any}/{reference}` in the route map meant that if the URL **started** with p- it would match??

Any assistance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I tried a different way of route mapping by adding a constraint and changing the url like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", "{any}/{reference}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Product", reference = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { any = @"^p-" });
```

This method doesnt work at all though.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

The example given in UPDATE (above) is workable, it just needs a slight adjustment to the constraint, as below:

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", "{any}/{reference}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Product", reference = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { any = @"^p-(.*)" });
```

The constraint `^p-` means that not only must the URL start with p-, but it must also only be p- i.e. it does not cater for any further text in the URL

Adding `(.*)` to the constraint means that the URL can end in anything else